# How to specify range of testcases to rerun in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have testcases 1 to 10 like,

```
testcase1
.
.
.
testcase2
.
.
.
testcase3
.
.
.
testcase(n)
```

I want to give rerun of testcases from 5 to 9. I am using following command now:

```
"pybot -t testcase5 testcase6 testcase7 testcase8 testcase9 example.robot"
```

Instead, how to specify this with range like "testcase5-9"?

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify range in command line options.

What you can do in described in the section [Using command line options](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-command-line-options) of the User Guide.

So for example, what you can do is `pybot -t testcase* example.robot` but that will run all your tests.

Options you have:

- rename tests that you might want to relaunch together: testcase_a1, testcase_a2, testcase_b1, and testcase_b1 => then launch `-t testcase_a*`
- use some [tags](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-tags) to create sub-groups of tests (and then launch them with [--include](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#by-tag-names))
- use [--rerunfailed](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#re-executing-failed-test-cases) if what you want to do is re-launched the failed tests

Comment: Thanks for giving me some info.